# Add root element to repeated nodes in XML file using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, root-node

I have XML file has repeated nodes, But don't have root element as the following:

```
<my-element>AAA</my-element>
<my-element>BBB</my-element>
<my-element>CCC</my-element>
```

I wanna generate XML with root as the following:

```
<my-root>
    <my-element>AAA</my-element>
    <my-element>BBB</my-element>
    <my-element>CCC</my-element>
</my-root>
```

I typed the following code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <my-root>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
  </my-root>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I received error because XML not formatted correctly:

```
The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
```

I know the Input should have root element. But Is there way to set root element for repeated elements without root using XSL?

Answer (score 0):

Your input is not a well-formed XML document, which is why you get this error. However, it could be seen as a node-set.

Depending on the XSLT processor used you may therefore be able to somehow pass the node-set in as a parameter, but there is no "standard way" of doing that.

However, it's probably simpler to just wrap the input document into some element and process this afterwards, e.g. concat `<root>` + file-content + `</root>` into a temporary file and use that as input for the transformation.